# Want to create tree like hierarchical structure for a custom object (Role__c) having self lookup relation

Tags: apex, visualforce

The tree will dynamically change its structure if 'Role_Reports_To__c'( a self look up field of 'Role__c' object) is changed.

The Mock Up is as given below:

[image]

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="RoleController" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
<title>Organization Structure</title>
<c:SCTHeader includeHeader="true"/> 
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Organization Structure</h1>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <strong><apex:outputLink value="roledetails?id={!role.ID}">{!role.Name}</apex:outputLink></strong>
                          <ul>     
                          <apex:repeat value="{!mainroles}" var="r">         
                             <li><strong><apex:outputLink value="roledetails?id={!r.boss.ID}">{!r.boss.Name}</apex:outputLink></strong></li> 
                                 <ul>
                                     <apex:repeat value="{!r.reportees}" var="re">
                                          <li><strong><apex:outputLink value="roledetails?id={!re.ID}">{!re.Name}</apex:outputLink></strong></li>
                                     </apex:repeat>                            
                                 </ul>
                          </apex:repeat>                     
                          </ul>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>  
            </tr>
        </table>   
    </div>    
 </body>
 <c:SCTFooter includeFooter="true"/>    
 </apex:page>
```

Apex Controller:

```
  public class RoleController {
      public List<Role__c> roles{get;set;}
      public Role__c role{get;set;}
      public list<FindChild> childRoleNode;

      public RoleController() {
          roles=[select Role__c.ID,Role__c.Name, Role__c.Description__c,Role__c.Role_Reports_To__c from Role__c where Role__c.Role_Reports_To__c=null order by CreatedDate];
          if(roles.size()>0){
             role=roles[0];
          }
      }

     //Inner Class to find child Roles
      public class FindChild{
         public Role__c boss{get;set;}
         public list<Role__c> reportees{get;set;}
         public FindChild(Role__c parentRole,list<Role__c> reporteeRoles){
             this.boss=parentRole;
             this.reportees=reporteeRoles;
         }
      }

      public list<FindChild> getmainroles(){
         childRoleNode = new List<FindChild>();
         List<Role__c> tempBoss = [Select Id,Name from Role__c where Role__c.Role_Reports_To__c!=null order by CreatedDate];

         for (Integer i =0; i< tempBoss.size() ; i++)
         {
             List<Role__c> tempReportee = [Select Id,Name from Role__c where Role_Reports_To__c = :tempBoss[i].Id];
             childRoleNode.add(new FindChild(tempBoss[i],tempReportee));
         } 
         return childRoleNode;
      }
   }
```

I have done so far with my code yet, but somehow nodes are repeating and I couldn't able to eliminate repetition of nodes which should appear in the hierarchy, I have also tried JavaScript remoting but didn't get expected result.

My Resultant Output is given below:

[image]

Comment: Why not the standard `UserRole`?

Answer (score 11):

Recursive data structures are fun, eh?

After looking over what you have now, I think you're on the right track. There are just some errors in the execution.

The nodes being repeated is a consequence of how your `getMainRoles()` method is written.

You query all roles that report to any other role, iterate over the results, query the current role's direct reports, and then create a node to link the current role to its direct reports.

This is happening for **every** role that has reports to another role. You're creating a `FindChild` record for 'VP Finance', whose direct report in your second image is 'Director Project Management'. You're also creating a `FindChild` record for 'Director Project Management' whose direct reports are 'Manager Project Management', 'Analyst I', and 'Analyst II'. Those 3 roles are having their own `Find Child` records created, etc...

Besides having the second query (which you actually don't need. I'll get into that later) inside a for loop (which is never a good idea), the big thing that you're missing is that you never link your `FindChild` nodes to one another to create a hierarchy that is more than one level deep.

**Making things work**

As is, your `FindChild` class doesn't quite work as a node class for use in a tree structure. To get the multi-level tree structure that you are looking for, you'll need to modify this inner class so that `reportees` is a `List<FindChild>` instead of a `List<Role__c>`

```
public class FindChild{
     public Role__c boss{get;set;}
     public List<FindChild> reportees{get;set;}

     // Getting rid of the List<Role__c> parameter in this constructor was done
     //   on purpose.
     // This will end up working with other changes to your code
     public FindChild(Role__c parentRole){
         this.boss = parentRole;
         this.reportees = new List<FindChild>();
     }
  }
```

The next step is to modify how you build this tree structure. This is where we'll get rid of that query inside the for loop.

```
public FindChild getmainroles(){
     FindChild rootNode;

     List<Role__c> reports = [Select Id,Name from Role__c where Role__c.Role_Reports_To__c!=null order by CreatedDate];

     // Instead of storing all the roles in a List, let's store them in a Map.
     // The 'ORDER BY CreatedDate' in your query doesn't really accomplish 
     //   anything, so I've removed it.
     Map<Id, Role__c> rolesMap = new Map<Id, Role__c>([Select Id,Name, Role_Reports_To__c from Role__c where Role__c.Role_Reports_To__c!=null]);

     // We need another map to store FindChild instances.
     // This will help prevent us from making duplicate instances.
     Map<Id, FindChild> nodesMap = new Map<Id, FindChild>();

     // The root of the hierarchy is what we'll end up returning.
     // Since this Role__c record isn't retrieved in the query we stored in
     //   rolesMap, we need to create the FindChild instance for it here,
     //   and insert it into the nodesMap.
     rootNode = new FindChild(role);
     nodesMap.put(role.Id, rootNode);

     // Now, we loop.
     // We can build the hierarchy in a single loop, but we need to be thoughtful
     //   in the execution.
     // We need to consider that we can end up working on a record at any random
     //   node within our hierarchy.
     // Thus, we can't assume that the parent to our current node has been created yet.
     FindChild currentNode;
     FindChild reportsTo;
     for(Role__c currentRole :rolesMap.values()){
         // Check to see if we have already created a FindChild instance for this role
         if(!nodesMap.containsKey(currentRole.Id)){
             nodesMap.put(currentRole.Id, new FindChild(currentRole));
         }

         currentNode = nodesMap.get(currentRole.Id);

         // Check to see if we've created a FindChild instance for the role that
         //   this role reports to.
         // This is why we need to store the queried roles in a Map instead of a List.
         if(!nodesMap.containsKey(currentRole.Role_Reports_To__c)){
             nodesMap.put(currentRole.Role_Reports_To__c, new FindChild(rolesMap.get(currentRole.Role_Reports_To__c)));
         }

         reportsTo = nodesMap.get(currentRole.Role_Reports_To__c);
         reportsTo.reports.add(currentNode);
     }

     return rootNode;
  }
```

That code should guarantee that we end up with your desired structure. The fun isn't over yet, however.

**Displaying your hierarchy in a visualforce page**

Visualforce doesn't like to handle nested structures very much. Doing so is a recipe for causing your viewstate to grow in size very quickly.

Generally speaking, you'd need to have a number of nested `<apex:repeat>` tags equal to the depth of your hierarchy. With your role hierarchy, that depth can change (over time, or between roles. VP Sales doesn't seem to have any direct reports, but VP Engineering does).

There are two ways I can think of to handle this.

1. Recursively render the visualforce/html
2. Use a recursive apex component

I'm afraid I don't have the time right now to confirm that either of these will work. I only have time to go over the first method (my answer is getting pretty long). The first method probably has a better chance of working.

For the first method, we'll need to change `getMainRoles()` and `FindChild` yet again. Instead of returning objects representing your role hierarchy, we'll return a string of html that represents your role hierarchy.

```
public class FindChild{
    <previous code omitted for brevity>

    // Here, we need to add a new, recursive method
    public String render(Boolean first){
        String result;

        // We can't put in the <ul> quite yet.
        // If we do, the output of this method will have a lot of extra <ul>...</ul> in it.
        // We'll take care of this later, this is why this method takes a boolean argument.
        result = '<li><strong><apex:outputLink value="roledetails?id={!r.boss.ID}">boss.Name</apex:outputLink></strong></li>\n';

        // Our recursive case.
        // If a node has more nodes below it, render those nodes.
        // This continues until we hit a 'leaf' node, one that doesn't have
        //   any nodes below it in the hierarchy
        if(!reportees.isEmpty()){
            // Wrap the list of children in a <ul></ul>.
            // Doing this here, and not in the 'base case' ensures that the lowest
            //   level in the hierarchy doesn't have an extraneous <ul></ul>
            result += '<ul>\n';

            for(FindChild child :reportees){
                result += child.render(false);
            }

            result += '</ul>\n';
        } else {
            // This is the 'base case' for our recursion.
            // If we assume that the recursive case will take care of wrapping
            //   everything inside of <ul></ul>, the only thing left for us to do
            //   is to render the <li>
            return '<li><strong><apex:outputLink value="roledetails?id=' + boss.ID + '">' + boss.Name + '</apex:outputLink></strong></li>\n';
        }

        // If we assume that everything up to now is correct, we still need to 
        //   wrap the highest level of the hierarchy in a <ul></ul> because
        //   the root of the hierarchy means it isn't a child of anything.
        //   (and we only wrap the result of rendering child nodes)
        if(firstRun){
            result = '<ul>\n' + result + '</ul>\n';
        }

        return result;

    }
  }
```

Your `getmainroles()` method would change to call this render method, and return a string.

```
// Notice that the return type changed
public String getmainroles(){
     <previous code omitted for brevity>

     /**
     *  This is the only line that has changed from the last example
     */
     return rootNode.render(true);
  }
```

Your visualforce would change to just simply display the result. This is the part that I'm not sure if it works or not. It depends on if Salesforce escapes html in strings.

```
<apex:page controller="RoleController" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
<title>Organization Structure</title>
<c:SCTHeader includeHeader="true"/> 
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Organization Structure</h1>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {!mainRoles}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<c:SCTFooter includeFooter="true"/>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solutions, I escaped the 'List<FindChild>' and used 'List<Role__c>' and ended up with mess. Anyway, I have taken care of the rendering which is okay now.

Comment: Nice answer! For the rendering part, you could also go for a VF component that recursively displays itself. I'm not sure if that would help in this case, just wanted to point it out.

Comment: @I am trying the similar apporach. But when i get response after Json.desirialze, i am not getting the results in nested format instead i'm getting all the details separately. can you please suggest me how you proceeded further. @Willem Mulder

Comment: @WillemMulder I am trying the similar apporach. But when i get response after Json.desirialze, i am **NOT** getting the results in nested format instead i'm getting all the details separately. can you please suggest me how you proceeded further.

Comment: @chandrakanth Neither of the people you have supplicated for help provided the answer to this question (and doing so is considered rude). Hijacking someone else's question is _very rude_. If you still have a question, ask it in a new question.

Comment: @DerekF My apologies that was not intentional!! but i did create 2 questions and I wasn’t able to achieve.so I started googling around more and found this approach very similar to my approach !!  Pls check this and if you could suggest me on what I am trying to achieve https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/209838/47564