# Tree Structure - Hierarchy Structure in visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

Good Old question but unable to figure out a easy way. can some one please guide me if anyone has faced this. I am working on dislaying a complex tree-branch-leaf structure.**All the Tree-Branch-Leaf** records will be inserted in same object with different record type. Please see the screenshot of what i am trying to build.
[image]

Can someone please guide me how can i Loop each record and create a Nested structure or Map so that a proper Json can be made. Since its a self look up to same object, it is becoming difficult

Answer (score 5):

This is one of those things best solved with a Visualforce Component, and a TreeNode class; this fixes the problem of how to deal with (potentially) infinite recursion in a sensible manner.

```
public class TreeNode {
  public TreeNode parent { get; set; }
  public Object value { get; set; } // Holds the value in this node
  public TreeNode[] children { get; set; } // Holds the value of child nodes
  public TreeNode(TreeNode p, Object v) {
    parent = p;
    value = v;
    children = value;
  }
}
```

---

```
<apex:component>
  <apex:attribute name="node" type="TreeNode[]" />
  <div>
  {!node.value}
  <div style="padding-left: 1em">
  <apex:repeat value="{!node.children}" var="child">
    <c:treeNode node="{!child}" />
  </apex:repeat>
  </div>
  </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

---

Your main page's controller will expose this value like this:

```
public class PageController {
  public TreeNode root { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

---

At this point, all you need to do is to populate the list of nodes.

To populate this efficiently, you need a Map. The general algorithm looks like this:

```
Map<Id, TreeNode> nodes = new Map<Id, TreeNode>();
// Populate parents
nodes.put(null, new TreeNode(null, null));
for(Object record: recordList) {
  nodes.put(record.Id, new TreeNode(null, record));
}
// Link parents
for(Object record: recordList) {
  if(record.parentid != null) {
    nodes.get(record.id).parent = nodes.get(record.parentid);
  }
}
// Populate children
for(Object record: recordList) {
  nodes.get(record.parentid).children(nodes.get(record.id));
}
root = nodes.get(null);
nodes = null; // the map is no longer needed.
```

The final output will be a single root node (identified by the Id null), that will contain a nested tree of all the items.

Note that this is a very, very rough draft that will need some manipulation for concrete data types, etc.

Note that this TreeNode implementation also includes a link to the parent node; this allows you to calculate the IdChain__c:

```
for(TreeNode node: nodes.values()) {
  String[] idChain = new String[] { '' }; // Temporary place holder
  TreeNode temp = node;
  while(temp != null) {
    idChain.add(0, temp.value.Id); // insert in first position, shifts all others up one
    temp = temp.parent;
  }
  idChain.remove(idChain.size()-1); // Remove temp place holder
  node.value.idChain__c = String.join(idChain, '.');
```

I realize this isn't necessarily a *full* answer, but it has all the essential parts that you'll need to complete your task.

Comment: thanks but i didn't get the Populate children part. So you are saying we need to iterate through each branch level records or all set of records? @sfdcfox

Comment: @chandrakanth The full set of records; the map takes care of filling out your branches for you. I actually have a demo of this (in Lightning) that is designed nearly identical as to how it's described here. I'll set up a gist for you.

Comment: @chandrakanth See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/32bd056260cf4850ba15bc5641b6c42f) for a demo in Lightning; the logic would be very similar in Visualforce; you need a treeNode component, it would have the ability to accept a tree node, it would show the name, then iterate over the list of children, etc.

Comment: Thanks for gist. I got the whole idea. However i am getting the following error. Since there is a character limit on the comment section i had to create a new post. Please see - [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210018/tree-structure-in-salesforce-using-self-relationship) @sfdcfox