# Tree Structure in salesforce using Self Relationship

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

In continuation to question - [PreviousQuestion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209838/tree-structure-hierarchy-structure-in-visual-force-page)

```
    public class myClassForTree{
    public TreeNode root { get; set; }
    public void constructTreeStructure(){
    List<Skill__c> skillset = [Select Id,HierarchyParentBranch__c,HierarchyRoot__c, Name,IdChain__c,recordType.id, Recordtype.Name from Skill__c where id in :hids]; **// hids - all ids which will 
                                 //return me root,branch and leaf at one query.** 
     Map<Id, TreeNode> nodes = new Map<Id, TreeNode>();
         //All Recs
        nodes.put(null, new TreeNode(null, null));

        for(Skill__c record: skillset ) {
          nodes.put(record.Id, new TreeNode(null, record));

        }  
        // Link parents
        for(Skill__c  record: skillset) {
          if(record.HierarchyParentBranch__c!= null) {                
            nodes.get(record.id).parentNode = nodes.get(record.HierarchyParentBranch__c);            
          }
        }  
        // Child parents
        for(Skill__c  record: skillset) {
          nodes.get(record.HierarchyParentBranch__c).children(nodes.get(record.id)); // Getting the following - Error: Compile Error: Method does not 
                                                                    //exist or incorrect signature: void children(myClassForTree.TreeNode) from the //type myClassForTree.TreeNode at line 21 
        }
    }
    public class TreeNode{
        public TreeNode parentNode { get; set; }
        public Skill__c value { get; set; } // Holds the value in this node
        public List<TreeNode> children { get; set; } // Holds the value of child nodes

        public TreeNode(TreeNode p, Skill__c v) {
            this.parentNode = p;
            this.value = v;
            this.children = value;// I am getting the following - Error Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Skill__c to 
                                  // List<myClassForTree.TreeNode> at line 32 column 18 

      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the below line, I believe you are trying to add the TreeNode records into the nodes map.

```
nodes.get(record.HierarchyParentBranch__c).children(nodes.get(record.id));
```

There is no method named children in TreeNode class, children is a property there, so you should be assigning into it, not call it. Like this-

```
nodes.get(record.HierarchyParentBranch__c).children = new List<TreeNode>{nodes.get(record.id)};
```

Next,

```
this.children = value;
```

`value` is of type `Skill__c`, `children` is of type `List<TreeNode>`, obviously incompatible. As per your given code, I think you need to initialize `children` with an empty list.

```
this.children = new List<TreeNode>();
```

Although this question was intended for sfdcfox, but I thought I should point out the cause of the compilation errors.